# Lucene A-Z list

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I would like to have an index view with A B C D E...in order to facet all my lucene results with the alphabet.

I have been googling around and I haven't found anything..

I tried with bobo facet library but id didn't work. I would like to obtain like an array like this:

```
Results{
   prefix A: 1 results
   prefix B: 2 results
   prefix C: 3 results 
   prefix D: 0 results 
....
}
```

This way I can disable or enable the buttons if I have results for the prefix.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

Thanks for your response!

Currently I am using Hibernate Search as core system. Moreover, to get facets I use BOBO library  (http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse). So, as you said before, I am thinking about creating a new field with the first word of the title. That way I can get the facets with BOBO.

For the moment I don't think about install SOLR.

I thought that I could find some code to avoid indexing this new field, I mean, the code to facet on a wilcard query, and not directly on a field, but I didn't find anything :)

Hibernator.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Solr (or ElasticSearch) instead of just plain Lucene?  If so, then all you would need to do is store the first letter of the word as a separate field on the indexed object and then do a facet search by that firstLetter field.  Solr (and ElasticSearch) has faceting out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Currently I am using Hibernate Search as core system. Moreover, to get facets I use BOBO library (http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse). So, as you said before, I am thinking about creating a new field with the first word of the title. That way I can get the facets with BOBO.

For the moment I don't think about install SOLR.

I thought that I could find some code to avoid indexing this new field, I mean, the code to facet on a wilcard query, and not directly on a field, but I didn't find anything :)

Hibernator.